# Is it possible to determine which properties of an object are inherited in Matlab without instantiating the parent class?

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance, properties

I have two classes, class1 and class2. Class2 inherits all properties from class1 and has some additional properties, e.g.:

```
classdef class1
    properties
        PropA
    end
    methods
        function instance1 = class1(arg1)
            ...
        end
    end
end


classdef class2 < class1
    properties
        PropB
    end
    methods
        function instance2 = class2(arg2)
            instance2 = instance2@class1(arg1)
            ...
    end
end
```

I call the constructor of class2

```
instance2 = class2(arg2)
```

and would subsequently like to know which properties of instance2 are inherited (i.e. PropA).

Is it possible to determine which properties of class2 are inherited, without creating an instance of class1 and subsequently comparing properties? If so, what would be an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine this information through [meta-classes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.html). In this case, to find the properties of class2 that are inherited (e.g., not defined by class2):

```
mcls = ?class2;
allProperties = mcls.PropertyList;
definedByClass2 = [allProperties.DefiningClass] == mcls;
inheritedProperties = allProperties(~definedByClass2);
propertyNames = {inheritedProperties.Name}
```

Note that you don't need an instance of *either* class to determine this information.